# XML files in res folder suddenly showing junk

Tags: android, android-studio

I am running `Android Studio 3.2` stable release on Windows 10.

All of a sudden, `layout` XML files and `string` XML files in the `res` folder are showing only junk, as below:

[image]

The `Translations Editor` however shows the strings are intact, but in red...

[image]

Tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the project
- `Invalidate Caches / Restart`
- Restarting Android Studio
- Restarting the system itself

Why has this happened and how can I fix it? Kindly help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not "junk", exactly: it's a PNG image file. Which I admit would be strange content for a strings.xml file... What does the file really look like, outside Android Studio? e.g. opening it directly in Notepad or another text editor?

Comment: @MattGibson, thanks. The `strings.xml` looks well-formed in Notepad++, no issues there at all...

Comment: Try copying the strings into a plain notepad. Then copying them from the notepad back into the strings.xml. I'm guessing your encoding got messed up somehow. Typically when you paste into plain text editors it changes it to the basic encoding and line ends etc that it needs. So copying it back out of the text editor may just do the trick you need. No guarantees, but worth a shot.

Comment: @Sam, thanks. Yep, was doing the exact same thing even while you were commenting. That's the only thing that works, and **guaranteed** too. If needed, do make it an answer so I can accept it. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @NarayanaJ sure I'll take the points, always helps. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying the strings into a plain notepad. 
Then copying them from the notepad back into the strings.xml. 
I'm guessing your encoding got messed up somehow. 
Typically when you paste into plain text editors it changes it to the basic encoding and line ends etc that it needs.

So copying it back out of the text editor may just do the trick you need. No guarantees, but worth a shot